# After submitting simple_form i get a blank page in show view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, submit, simple-form

I have created a simple form, the user click on three items and press submit and an email is being send, all of this works. However, when i test it and check the show page, it doesn't show any entered details which were selected by the user, just a blank page.i don't receive any errors.

**controller**

```
class PositionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @position = Position.new
  end

  def show
    @position = Position.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @position = Position.new(position_params)
    if @position.save
      PositionMailer.general_message(@position).deliver
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private def position_params
    params.permit(:date, :time, :activity)
  end
end
```

**view**

```
<div class="form">
  <%= simple_form_for @position  do |f| %>
    <div class= "trip">
        <div class="trip-text">
          Trip number
        </div>
        <div class="trip-field">
          <%= f.input :tripnumber, label: false, placeholder: 'enter here' %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class= "activity">
      <div class="activity-text">
        Activity
      </div>
      <div class="activity-field">
        <%= f.input :activity, label: false, collection: [['Sailing to loadport, expected arrival', 'Sailing to loadport, expected arrival'], ['Sailing to discharge port, expected arrival', 'Sailing to discharge port, expected arrival'],
          ['Loading untill', 'Loading untill'], ['Discharging untill', 'Discharging untill'], ['Waiting for loading, expect to start', 'Waiting for loading, expect to start'], ['Waiting for discharge, expect to start', 'Waiting for discharge, expect to start']] %>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="date">
      <div class="date-text">
        Date
      </div>
      <div class="date-field">
        <%= f.date_field :date, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="time">
      <div class="time-text">
        Time
      </div>
      <div class="time-field">
        <%= f.time_field :time, value: "%H:%M", min: 'hh:mm:ss', max: 'hh:mm:ss' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <%= f.submit "Send update", class: "submit"%>
</div>
```

Since i have no error and all works fine except i dont have the input of the users i dont know where to look, i looked in the forum and on google but no succes

Comment: i added a redirect now but still a blanko sheet with no error message

Comment: yes i called save!

Comment: this is my show view: <h2><%= @position.activity %></h2>

Comment: After you call PositionMailer you are not doing anything. You should go to show or index.  For example, format.html { redirect_to :Action => 'index' } should display the added item in the main list.

Comment: i added a redirect in the controller to showpage but nothing changes, it redirects me to an empty show page :(

Comment: so the show page works, but no input from the simple_form_for, is there a way to check if my input of the form for is being saved? when i write regular text in the show page i can see it, so only the input of the form doesnt show

Comment: i figured it out, forgot to add required params in the controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `create` action, add `redirect_to @position`

```
if @position.save
  PositionMailer.general_message(@position).deliver
  redirect_to @position
else
  render :new
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks it was this + forgot to add required params in the controller :)